# Criar e ler DLL em php?

Tags: php, c#, dll

Seria possível criar e abrir bibliotecas DLL de windows em php?

Quero organizar minhas classes php em dll para que possam ser utilizadas em tanto em php quanto C#, caso exista alguma alternativa também serve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando a classe [COM](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php).

Mas antes, você tem que registrar a dll no windows executando esse comando no prompt:

```
REGSVR32 MinhaDll.dll
```

Agora que a dll está registrada, você faz isso para acessar a DLL:

```
$minha_dll = new COM(‘MinhaDll.Objeto’);
```

"minha_dll" é o nome da dll e Objeto é o objeto dentro da dll que você quer utilizar. Agora, por exemplo, para chamar um método dentro da sua dll que encripte um texto:

```
$texto_encriptado = null;
$input = ‘Texto que vai ser encriptado.’;
$minha_dll->EncriptaString($input, $texto_encriptado );
```

(supondo que você tenha um método chamado EncriptaString que aceita esses tipos de parâmetro)

Comment: Excelente muito obrigado pela ajuda.!

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível abrir ficheiros DLL através de um servidor Apache/Unix. Tenha em consideração esse facto.

Caso esteja a usar um servidor IIS, penso que [esta](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.com.php#faq.com.q6) leitura pode ser útil. Terá de usar um servidor COM e usar IDispatch mas, não é garantido que funcione.

Comment: João, DLL é um termo bastante genérico e não um formato específico. O que definirá se é possível abrir ficheiros nesse formato no Linux, ou com Apache, são os dados contidos no ficheiro.

Answer (score 1):

Não use esse tipo de nomenclatura para **PHP**, ainda não está garantido que tudo funcione do jeito que se espera, e a versão do [php](/questions/tagged/php) são as mais atuais (5.4.5), sendo que em muitos servidores não acompanham tal atualização e pelo link do site as suas [dependências](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/com.requirements.php), requerem PHP For Windows e .Net Support e consequentemente servidor [iis](/questions/tagged/iis), sendo que o [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) não roda.